# SQL0100W Error on DB2

Tags: db2, peoplesoft

I get the following error when running an sqr report on DB2:

```
SQL0100W - No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
```

The sql in question runs correctly when I paste it into RapidSQL, replacing the parameters. The sql in question is an insert-select. No rows are returned by the select, and this is fine... I expect the report to be blank for my parameters.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be an environment setup issue. Got resolved with no change from me after a couple of builds....

Strange :-/

Answer (score 1):

DB2 returns always an SQL0100 warning (this is a warning, not an error - errors would have negative values) when no rows are returned. That's the way it is.
I don't know peoplesoft at all - so I can't give you any pointers with that. Back when I was programming for DB2 we ignored those SQL0100 warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way to ignore this warning! My SQR terminates after printing out this message. Instead of generating a (blank) PDF report as it's supposed to. . . 

But thank you for the information!

Comment: too bad - this was one of the more annoying things of DB2.

Answer (score 1):

If SQR can't gracefully handle a NOT_FOUND SQL0100 return, then code a preliminary query to return a count of the number of rows that satisfy the conditions of the actual query. Check the result of the count in an if-then block in SQR to run the actual query if and only if the row count returned by the preceding query was not zero.

Answer (score 0):

if you delete delete more than one record using logic operation like delete from tabname where columnnmae=deleterecord and columnnmae=deleterecord then they show this type error.machine an

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.